# Android:Eclipse strange behaviour for main.xml?

Tags: android, eclipse

when i try to open main.xml it disappeared.after that i read the following link.

[Unable to open both main.xml files from layout & layout-land at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485454/unable-to-open-both-main-xml-files-from-layout-layout-land-at-the-same-time)

from that i am able to open main.xml but when i try to **drag a component to it disappears(eclipse crashes).**

is there anybody here to help?

thankx

Comment: Please update your post with the version of eclipse, the SDK and the android plugin that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a problem of jvm crashes,so i have just change the jdk(jdk-6u23-windows-i586) and its works fine.

thankx a lot guys for reply.

thankx